# Rewrite the URL based on page name

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I have a site that contains URL https://app.bitlabtech.com/ for normal users and for admin users https://app.bitlabtech.com/manager/

After the client login to the site, it redirects to https://app.bitlabtech.com/?page=home and when they request another page like send mail then the URL looks like https://app.bitlabtech.com/?page=sendEmail. I want to rewrite the URL to https://app.bitlabtech.com/home instead of https://app.bitlabtech.com/?page=home and https://app.bitlabtech.com/sendEmail instead of https://app.bitlabtech.com/?page=sendEmail.

Code running on UBUNTU 20.04 apache server.

For better understanding, I have attached my PHP code here

````
    public static $page = "page";
    public static $folder = PAGES_DIR;

    public static function getParam($param = null){
        if(!empty($param)) {
            return isset($_GET[$param]) && $_GET[$param] != "" ? $_GET[$param] : null;
        }
    }

    public static function cPage(){
        return isset($_GET[self::$page]) ? $_GET[self::$page] : "index";
    }

    public static function getPage(){
        $page = self::$folder.DS.self::cPage().".php";
        $error = self::$folder.DS."error.php";

        return is_file($page) ? $page : $error;
    }

    public static function getReferrerUrl() {
        $page = self::getParam(Login::$_referrer);
        return !empty($page) ? "/?page={$page}" : null;
    }   
}

?>```
````

Comment: the PHP code above is irrelevant, what you should be posting is your Apache configuration i.e. httpd.conf or apache2.conf or .htaccess as you are going to create a rewrite rule using mod_rewrite in Apache to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: The PHP code for showing how my URL is forming not for the rewrite. 
Can you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: You just need to say what your url is and what you want it to be like what you have done in your first paragraph.  That is enough information to be able to create a rewrite  rule in the apache config file. And then you should post what your current apache config is so that people can show you how to integrate a rerite rule

Answer (score 0):

assuming index.php is index file the following code will allow apache to catch pretty url and call the right php

```
RewriteEngine On
# any word without slash
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$   index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But you need to change your code to use these pretty urls

Comment: That not works for me. What do I need to change, please?
I have tried using the following code in my  .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$   index.php?page=$1 [L]`